# How to split QCircuit figure in multiple rows

Tags: formatting, size, qcircuit

I am using Qiskit's `draw('latex_source')` method to get a latex figure of my circuit. This circuit has high depth and thus is very wide.
I want it to be split into multiple rows, like using the `fold` argument with Qiskit's `mpl` or ASCII drawings.

Is there a simple way to automatically split the circuit into multiple folds?

EDIT:
Example: Suppose this is the figure:

```
\documentclass[border=5px]{standalone}
\usepackage[braket, qm]{qcircuit}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\scalebox{1.0}{{$\mathrm{global\,phase:\,} \mathrm{\frac{\pi}{2}}$}
\Qcircuit @R=1em @C=0.75em { \\
        \nghost{{q}_{0} :  } & \lstick{\ket{0}} & \gate{\mathrm{H}} & \qw & \qw & \qw & \qw & \qw & \qw & \qw & \qw & \qw & \qw & \targ & \gate{\mathrm{R_Z}\,(\mathrm{-1.0})} & \targ & \qw \\
        \nghost{{q}_{1} :  } & \lstick{\ket{0}} & \gate{\mathrm{H}} & \ctrl{1} & \qw & \ctrl{1} & \gate{\mathrm{H}} & \gate{\mathrm{R_X}\,(\mathrm{\frac{\pi}{2}})} & \ctrl{1} & \qw & \ctrl{1} & \gate{\mathrm{R_Z}\,(\mathrm{\frac{\pi}{2}})} & \gate{\mathrm{R_Y}\,(\mathrm{-0.5})} & \qw & \qw & \qw& \qw  \\
        \nghost{{q}_{2} :  } & \lstick{\ket{0}} & \gate{\mathrm{H}} & \targ & \gate{\mathrm{R_Z}\,(\mathrm{-1.0})} & \targ & \gate{\mathrm{H}} & \gate{\mathrm{R_X}\,(\mathrm{\frac{\pi}{2}})} & \targ & \gate{\mathrm{R_Z}\,(\mathrm{-1.0})} & \targ & \gate{\mathrm{R_X}\,(\mathrm{\frac{-\pi}{2}})} & \qw & \ctrl{-2} & \qw & \ctrl{-2} & \qw \\
\\ }}
\end{document}
```

This figure is too long for a single row (this is just an example, actual figure is 5 times more wide). Thus I would want this to be split into two rows.

Comment: What is your minimal working example? Please can you put it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Funny, I was about to ask the exact same question when I found yours from just a day ago. What I finally did is to solve the issue on the Qiskit side using the following LayeredCircuit class:

```
from qiskit import QuantumCircuit
from qiskit.converters import circuit_to_dag, dag_to_circuit

class LayeredCircuit:
"""Turn ciruit into list of circuits of depth 1"""

    def __init__(self, circuits = []):
        self._current_index = 0
        self._layers = []
        self.num_qubits = 0
        arg_error = 'Argument must be one of QuantumCircuit, LayeredCircuit,
                     or list of QuantumCircuits of equal size.'
        if isinstance(circuits, QuantumCircuit):
            circuits = [circuits]
        if isinstance(circuits, LayeredCircuit):
            circuits = circuits._layers
        if not isinstance(circuits, list):
            raise TypeError(arg_error)
        if circuits:
            self.num_qubits = len(circuits[0].qubits)
        for circuit in circuits:
            if not isinstance(circuit, QuantumCircuit):
                raise TypeError(arg_error)
            if not len(circuit.qubits) == self.num_qubits:
                raise TypeError(arg_error)
            dag = circuit_to_dag(circuit)
            for layer in dag.layers():
                qc = dag_to_circuit(layer['graph'])
                qc.global_phase = 0 # ignore all global phases
                self._layers.append(qc)

    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    def __next__(self):
        if self._current_index < len(self.layers):
            l = self._layers[self._current_index]
            self._current_index += 1
            return l
        else:
            raise StopIteration
        
    def __getitem__(self, i):
        if isinstance(i, slice):
            return LayeredCircuit(self._layers[i])
        elif isinstance(i, int):
            return self._layers[i]
        else:
            raise TypeError('Invalid argument type.')

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self._layers)

    def append(self, other):
        """Appends another LayeredCircuit"""
        if not isinstance(other, LayeredCircuit):
            other = LayeredCircuit(other)
        for layer in other:
            self._layers.append(layer)

    def merge(self):
        """Returns the merged QuantumCircuit of all layers"""
        qc = QuantumCircuit(self.num_qubits)
        for layer in self._layers:
            qc.compose(layer,range(self.num_qubits),inplace=True)
        return qc
    
    def draw(self, *args, **kwargs):
        """Draws the merged circuit, same syntax as QuantumCircuit.draw()"""
        return self.merge().draw(*args, **kwargs)

    def latex(self):
        """Returns LaTeX Qcircuit code"""
        doc = self.draw('latex_source')
        return '\Qcircuit' + doc.split('\Qcircuit')[1].split('}\n\end{document}')[0]
```

You can then print parts of your circuit, e.g.

```
print(LayeredCircuit(qc)[0:5].latex())
```

For my purpose, I combined it with a loop:

```
c = LayeredCircuit(qc)
l = len(c)
n = 17
for i in range(l//n+1):
    print('&\\begin{array}{c}\\tiny')
    print(c[i*n:min(l,(i+1)*n)].latex())
    print('\\end{array}\\\\')
```

which I then copy&pasted into an align environment in LaTeX.

Comment: PS: I'm aware that this is not really an answer to the question how to split a Qcircuit drawing, but it solves the more specific issue how to split circuits exported from Qiskit.